# How to restore nuget packages from CLI like Visual Studio does

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

We have a script to build our application in C#. We have most of projects in .NET7 which builds fine but I am dealing with old .NET Framework projects. We cannot upgrade those projects (or it will take a lot of time which we don't have now) because of missing libraries, so this is not the way.

We have installed Visual Studio 2022, where I found MSBuild. When I try to build it with following command it builds when I opened the solution in Visual Studio earlier.

```
msbuild /p:OutputPath=<path-to-publish-folder>;Configuration=Release <path-to-csproj-file>
```

It does not work when it is just cloned repository. That is because Visual Studio creates a folder packages in folder where is the *.sln file and we have the CLI build scripts in the same folder.

How to download the nuget package from CLI with installed .NET7 SDK and Visual Studio 2022? The destination folder should be /packages.

I tried `msbuild <path-to-csproj> -t:restore`, also `msbuild project.sln -t:restore`. Both commands restores nuget packages for referenced netstandard dependent project according to it's output but it does not restore the ngets of the main project.

I also tried `dotnet msbuild <path-to-csproj> /t:restore` but the output is:

```
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
```

The solution was created in Visual Studio and also all nuget dependencies were managed via Visual Studio.

Which command should I use to restore the nugets to ./packages folder like Visual Studio does on project opening?

Comment: Can you use the `nuget.exe` cli directly?

Comment: @gunr2171 the nuget.exe cli is not installed on every computer here so it would be better without it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dotnet restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) to restore dependencies and add a `-f` to force it.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. When I run it with path to the .NET Framework project then it restores only referenced netstandard project and when I run it for whole solution then the output shows only net-7 and netstandard projects. Old .NET Framework projects are missing in the output and ./packages folder is not created.